# remember-me not working with Persistent Tokens

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have implemented remember-me in my application using Spring security. I am implementing it using PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeService. This is working fine when I am using:

```
 <remember-me key="springRocks" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
```

I see that entries are getting created in persistent_logins table. Now I tried removing remember-me checkbox in my login page and have set attribute 'alwaysRemember' to true when defining PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeService bean expecting that I now need not click the checkbox and it will be always remembered.Here is how I did it:

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeService" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="key" value="springRocks"/>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="tokenRepository"/>
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And I have overridden my remember me as:

```
<remember-me services-alias="rememberMeService" key="springRocks" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
```

Now remember-me functionality is not working. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: With the changes do you see remember me being added to the database?How is it not working (i.e. error on startup, i do the following and x happens but I expect y to happen, etc)? Did you try turning on logging? What do the logs look like?

Comment: As I have set 'alwaysRemember' property to true, I have removed the remember me check-box from my login.jsp. Now when I login, I expected that entry will be created in persistent_logins as 'alwaysRemeber' is true. But it is not created. 

Also I have kept a debug point in PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices and saw the value of 'alwaysRemember'. It is coming as false though I have declared in the bean definition as 'true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your configuration to use [servies-ref](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-remember-me-services-ref) instead of [services-alias](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-remember-me-services-alias).

```
<remember-me 
    services-ref="rememberMeService" 
    key="springRocks" 
    data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
```

The services-alias is for being able to reference the RememberMeServices created by the  element in the event another object needs a reference to it. The services-ref will allow you to use your own RememberMeServices instance.